# Can't change values in destination view after segue

Tags: uitableview, segue

I have a simple master/detail tableview. In order to get my selection in the master to the detail view, I use the following code to set a label (lTest) in the detail view.

However, it seems that this code is run before/ on a different view, since it does not return an error, but the value of lTest is not changed (not visible on screen after the segue).

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];        
        ViewController *Targetview = segue.destinationViewController;
        Targetview.lTest.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d",indexPath.item];
    }
}
```

How can I change the label in the other view?

Answer (score 1):

Your new controller isn't expected to have any of its views set up until it executes `viewDidLoad:`.  Give it a string property to hold the text that you want `lTest` to have and store to that during `prepareForSegue:`, then update your label's text inside `ViewController` one it has its views.

Comment: Thanks man!!! you saved my life, half a day trying to find out what was happening, lots of tutorials and no one said this! 100 Thanks